# Segmentation Error for C code

Tags: c, unix

I am new to C and trying to write a simple Ceaser cipher program a->b->c and so on. So far the code compiles, but I get an Error 139, when I looked this up it came up as a segmentation error. I have never had this happen before and wonder if anyone could take a look and see what I am doing wrong?

Hello thanks everyone for the help, the 139 error is not present anymore my updated code is below that works :D.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   char strg [100], ch;
   int i;

   printf ("Enter a string\n");
   scanf ("%s" , strg);
   for (i = 0; strg [i] != '\0';  ++i)
   {
      ch = strg[i];
      if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
      {
        ch = ch + 1;

        if(ch > 'z')
        {
          ch = ch - 'z' + 'a' -1;
        }
        strg[i] = ch;
      }

   }
   printf ("The string is %s", strg);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ch = &strg[i]`;` -- doesn't your compiler warn you here? (Is this actually the code that you have compiled? The `Return` with a capital R is suspicious.

Comment: No this is a picture of what i get when i compile https://gyazo.com/e811e8672213f4ebef1e9e4b4acdf239

Comment: As I suspected: The code in the question isn't the same as the one you compile. Why do you do that? Copy and paste the actual code, please.

Comment: the funny curly quotes gave that away already :)

Comment: `if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')` and similar are non-portable.  Only the digits `0`-`9` are guaranteed to be represented consecutively.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Sure, this industrial-strength Caesar-shifting program is going to be ported to a lot of EBCDIC machines. By the look of it, the OP has other problems at the moment than to worry about portability.

Comment: @MOehm The earlier the questioner learns that **everthing** matters when writing C code, the better code he'll write.

Comment: The problem is not reproducible, the code [doesn't compile](https://ideone.com/DNjSDM).

Answer (score 4):

It's a typo in `printf (“The string is %s, strg”);`, where you actually do not provide a parameter for `%s`.

Write

```
printf ("The string is %s", strg);
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using function `scanf` to scan string, it is fint to tell the limit of scanned characters, so if your array has 100 bounds, do following

```
scanf ("%99s" , strg);  // Leave one byte for null terminating character
```

---

Also here

```
ch = &strg[i];
```

you are assigning `char*` to `char`, remove the `&` reference operator (which is used for getting variables address here)

```
ch = strg[i];
```

---

And finally this

```
printf ("The string is %s, strg");
```

Would lead to undefined behavior (some undefined data would be picked from stack), i guess you wanted to do following

```
printf ("The string is %s", strg);
```